# Create two record across hour end with same information

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, recursive-query

I want to split a single row into multiple rows based on time. Below is the example data.

```
Status  MachineId        StartDate                  EndDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN      1               2018-08-20 07:27:00.000    2018-08-20 08:23:00.000
IDLE     1               2018-08-20 08:23:01.000    2018-08-20 08:38:00.000
RUN      1               2018-08-20 08:38:01.000    2018-08-20 09:20:00.000
STOP     1               2018-08-20 09:20:01.000    2018-08-20 11:11:00.000
```

Expected output is below:

```
Status  MachineId        StartDate                  EndDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN      1               2018-08-20 07:27:00.000    2018-08-20 07:59:59.000
RUN      1               2018-08-20 08:00:00.000    2018-08-20 08:23:00.000
IDLE     1               2018-08-20 08:23:01.000    2018-08-20 08:38:00.000
RUN      1               2018-08-20 08:38:01.000    2018-08-20 08:59:59.000
RUN      1               2018-08-20 09:00:00.000    2018-08-20 09:20:00.000
STOP     1               2018-08-20 09:20:01.000    2018-08-20 09:59:59.000
STOP     1               2018-08-20 10:00:00.000    2018-08-20 10:59:59.000
STOP     1               2018-08-20 11:00:00.000    2018-08-20 11:11:00.000
```

The last "event" of the hour is also replicated for the following hours, considering the start and end time, until a new event change is taken.

Comment: To begin with. What are you trying to achieve and why do you think that adding more entries will serve you better?

Comment: Why does the current table records have to change and split records to 3 or 4 based on time? Are you sure that this is the best tactic?

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select status, machineid, 
        startdate,
        dateadd(hour, 1, datetimefromparts(year(startdate), month(startdate), day(startdate), datepart(hour, startdate), 0, 0, 0)) as enddate,
        enddate as maxdate
    from mytable
    union all
    select status, machineid, enddate, dateadd(hour, 1, enddate), maxdate
    from cte
    where enddate < maxdate
)
select status, machineid, startdate, 
    case when enddate < maxdate then enddate else maxdate end as enddate
from cte
order by startdate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6293608d0ac93c95a30959c77326b256)**:

```
status | machineid | startdate               | enddate                
:----- | --------: | :---------------------- | :----------------------
RUN    |         1 | 2018-08-20 07:27:00.000 | 2018-08-20 08:00:00.000
RUN    |         1 | 2018-08-20 08:00:00.000 | 2018-08-20 08:23:00.000
IDLE   |         1 | 2018-08-20 08:23:01.000 | 2018-08-20 08:38:00.000
RUN    |         1 | 2018-08-20 08:38:01.000 | 2018-08-20 09:00:00.000
RUN    |         1 | 2018-08-20 09:00:00.000 | 2018-08-20 09:20:00.000
STOP   |         1 | 2018-08-20 09:20:01.000 | 2018-08-20 10:00:00.000
STOP   |         1 | 2018-08-20 10:00:00.000 | 2018-08-20 11:00:00.000
STOP   |         1 | 2018-08-20 11:00:00.000 | 2018-08-20 11:11:00.000
```

This uses half-open date ranges rather than substracting 1 second from the upper bound, because that makes more sense to me. You can easily adapt the query to offset the upper bound if that's what you really want.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried but I receive the error: "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.".

Comment: @Alberto: if you have ranges that span over more than 100 hours, then you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.